# Cannot get newPassword to generate strong password and autofill

Tags: swift, security, ios12

I'm trying to get autofill working.  Specifically, either of [these](https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/seamless-login-experience-with-password-autofill-and-shared-web-credentials-6a232fa5f54d) [experiences](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/apples-password-less-future-is-strong-passwords/).  The former being the one I'm more interested in, but two for the sake of having more than one example.

Everything is working except the strong password generation.

I've correctly configured my AASA, I've switched everything to SSL, textContentType is correctly set, I enabled the autofill provider entitlement (after reading more I'm turning it back off though since that's not what I want (same results)).  Is there something in info.plist i'm missing?  I am using a keychain library to access the keychain? but I don't think that's it.

Specifically I'm trying to get to [this screen](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*m5gdFQRhjullvhDQc4Th_Q.png)

Any suggestions of where to dig would also be appreciated.  At this point I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if ios12 is new and doesn't work right yet.

Relevant code? (This is all I have in the 'code', am I missing somethign somewhere else?)

```
pwTF.textContentType = .newPassword
pwTF.passwordRules = UITextInputPasswordRules(descriptor: "required: upper; required: lower; required: digit; max-consecutive: 2; minlength: 16;")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you have a UITextField that has the `usernameTextField.textContentType = .username` on the same page? I only got the strong password suggestion after I added the username field.

Comment: Any other requirement? I have a username type with email keyboard, a newpassword type, associated domain with the required apple file, and I still don't get the suggestions..

Comment: If you have a ssl proxy in the middle (Charles?) password autofill doesn't work.

Comment: Turns out I had to enable "iCloud Keychain" on the phone settings to "On"..

Answer (score 1):

I know it may be solved already for you but here is a solution for generations to come :)

Sometimes it doesn't work cause your device have the keychain turned off.. go to Settings -> AppleID -> iCloud ->  KeyChain .. and enable it .

Answer (score 0):

i guess it's heuristics based and if it can't find a username field it's unhappy?

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: So what if we want if to change the password?