# How to trigger "Suggest New Password" in iOS textField using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, keychain

When using the SwiftUI TextField, I use `SecureField` to have the password treatment.  However it is only giving the option to access previously established passwords.

[image]

How can I make it suggest a new password, as this is a signup form that I am working on.

This is what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It should be as simple as `yourTextField.contentType = .newPassword`.

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. You must:

1. Also have a [text field set to `.username`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53226435/14351818)

[image: Username text field above NewPassword text field]

2. Enable iCloud Keychain, otherwise [you get this error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58383055/14351818):

> [AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: com.aheze.YOURAPP due to error: iCloud Keychain is disabled

3. And even after that, [you get this error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64363915/14351818) (which seems to be an iOS 14 problem):

> [KBDAnalyticsLog] -[TIAnalyticsService _registerEventSpec:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke TIAnalyticsEventSpec with name 'thirdPartyKeyboards' is already registered.

All in all, it's very broken. I couldn't get it to work.

#### Similar issues

- [Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667389)
- [iOS 14 doesn’t auto suggest saved website passwords](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251963211)